# Не работает оператор ИЛИ в регулярном выражении. java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь написать регулярное выражение для поиска чисел в тексте. Не только целых, но и дробных, в формате с точкой и запятой. Вот код:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class NumberFinder {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String text = "Это текст с числами 456. Также здесь есть число 7890 77.3 90,1.";
    
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)|(\\d+(\\,\\d+)?)"); // Регулярное выражение для поиска чисел
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    
            boolean found = false;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Найдено число: " + matcher.group());
                found = true;
            }
    
            if (!found) {
                System.out.println("Чисел не найдено!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Когда ставлю два условия в выражение через или, не работает ни одно, а по отдельности работают, как исправить?

Comment: если какой-то из ответов оказался полезным, можете принять его, поставив зелёную галочку.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение не работает из-за так называемого порядка альтернатив. Сначала необходимо, чтобы был поиск чисел с точкой или запятой, а уже потом был поиск только целых чисел.

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+[.,]\\d+)|\\d+");`

Answer (score 0):

Соседний ответ лучше, но ещё можно убрать вопросик у первой части: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##jZHNbtNAEIDveYqpT7ZatkX8hGJF3LiBkDhSDpt4k26wvdZ6XYqgEgmHHkDiCZCqXjghRVBDSCC8wuwThVnXhqQtEnPY2Zmdmf1mZsgP@DWViXQYPVsuZZIpbWBITlYYGTMtBuKQPeCmty902PrH@yNujNBp2GoBSS/meQ4Pi6Qr9H2ZRkLDy@rBSVZ0Y9mD3HBD6kDJCBIuU/@x0TIdPHkKXA/yYCXByfkjGHFooAMefrJjXAAdJc7syI7BjsAe49SOcI4T/IFTuHnrNgM8JWuGX7EE/IZnWFLwO6jUmC5/UhbQvrO7A@02uwG7O1vXmRdW/69B1E1CVutO42E9lWQyFr7n7@1Fm3Qwp4PgVWNvVfa9wAtC2N4GPCHwL/YNzu17@xp/4sIBfrZvyZg4WnJNnevMRQD@ogAHOsNJw1zifA2u3hDN8lx3GkxWe3w3vOCKtrpKxYKn0FdFGlFen8e5CNdCnu9Td@DXlVifduoHF3dU7elFbkTCVGFYRhszcep7@IF6@u6G7xpdmfld8GCzAWYDrYqMqoaXijZgRhcXuI4udyP74G9UGf/N97EZKBBg6Y4V3g0vuOrPv7ej5fI3)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(\\.\\d+))|(\\d+(\\,\\d+)?)");
```

Исходный вариант не работает из-за того, что регулярка уже нашла совпадение по первой ветви и у неё нет причин его откатывать.

Вот более простой пример этой же ситуации:

```js
console.log("abc".match(/a|ab|abc/)[0]) // a
console.log("abc".match(/ab|a|abc/)[0]) // ab
console.log("abc".match(/abc|ab|a/)[0]) // abc
```

Поэтому при объединении через ИЛИ, как правило, стоит делать так, чтобы совпадение по более ранним ветвям не могло быть префиксом совпадения более поздних.

Answer (score 0):

> *Когда ставлю два условия в выражение через или, не работает ни одно, а по отдельности работают, как исправить?*

Утверждение неверно.  Код, представленный в вопросе, будет обрабатывать числа *с плавающей точкой `.`*, а вот числа с запятой будут разбиты на две части, так как в регулярке первая "альтернатива" обрабатывает именно точку:

```java
String text = "Это текст с числами 456. Также здесь есть число 7890 77.3 90,1.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)|(\\d+(\\,\\d+)?)");
```

```
Найдено число: 456
Найдено число: 7890
Найдено число: 77.3
Найдено число: 90
Найдено число: 1
```

---

Если есть необходимость считать десятичным разделителем точку ИЛИ запятую, то регулярку следует исправить:

- с использованием ИЛИ `|`: `Pattern.compile("\\d+((\\.|,)\\d+)?")`
- с использованием множества символов: `Pattern.compile("\\d+([.,]\\d+)?")`
  Результат в обоих случаях:

```
Найдено число: 456
Найдено число: 7890
Найдено число: 77.3
Найдено число: 90,1
```

---

Также можно добавить альтернативу для обработки чисел, которые не содержат целой части и *начинаются* с десятичного разделителя (тогда дробная часть будет обязательна):

```java
String text = ".45 Это текст с числами 456. Также здесь есть число 7890 77.3 90,1 или даже ,31415.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+([.,]\\d+)?|([.,]\\d+)");
```

```
Найдено число: .45
Найдено число: 456
Найдено число: 7890
Найдено число: 77.3
Найдено число: 90,1
Найдено число: ,31415
```